# How to fix syntax error in update statement vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

**My Code are:**

```
Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand("Update Account Name'" & txtAccountName.Text & "', Age='" & txtAccountAge.Text & "', Degress='" & cboAccountDegress.Text & "', Birthday='" & txtAccountBirthday.Text & "', Address='" & txtAccountAddress.Text & "', Number='" & txtAccountNumber.Text & "', Gender='" & txtAccountNumber.Text & "' where ID=" & txtAccountID.Text & "", conn)

            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtAccountID.Text)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtAccountName.Text)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtAccountAge.Text)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Degress", cboAccountDegress.Text)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", txtAccountBirthday.Text)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAccountAddress.Text)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtAccountNumber.Text)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cboAccountGender.Text)

            conn.Open()
            cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()

            bind_data()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UPDATE should make use of Parameter place holders like:

```
Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand("Update Account SET [Name]=@Name, Age=@Age, Degress=@Degress, Birthday=@Birthday, Address=@Address, [Number]=@Number, Gender=@Gender where ID=@ID", conn)
```

In addition, your `UPDATE` statement also had a missing `SET` keyword and you also have to be aware of using Reserved Words for column names and wrap any conflicting columns with square brackets, see how I have updated the `Name` and `Number` columns in the UPDATE statement

And then alter the order in which you add parameters to put the Id parameter last:

```
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtAccountName.Text)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtAccountAge.Text)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Degress", cboAccountDegress.Text)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", txtAccountBirthday.Text)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAccountAddress.Text)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtAccountNumber.Text)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cboAccountGender.Text)
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtAccountID.Text)
```

For connections based on OleDb, the parameter order in the SQL statement should match the order the parameters are added to the `Parameters` collection

Comment: still Syntax error in UPDATE

Comment: @DevilBlacklist Can you tell me which database you are using please? Is it MS Access ?

Comment: Microsoft Access the only i know data base

Comment: @DevilBlacklist `Number` is a reserved word in MS Access. See [List of reserved words in Access 2002 and in later versions of Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words) for a full list of reserved words. If you have a column that is the same as a reserved word you need to wrap it with square brackets. E.g. `[Name]` and `[Number]`. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: no wait its okay now

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQL Server Update Function

```
UPDATE TableName
```

Set the column name you want to update

```
SET Column1 = @Column1 ,Column2 = @Column2
```

And define the condition using where

```
Where Column3 = ‘Condition’
```